# How can i simulate erosion and corrosion on objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, modifiers

It´s possible to simulate corrosion and erosion on object geometry and texture ?
[image]

So, what im trying to ask, is if it´s possible to simulate erosion on this blocks. By Geometry and texture. Like reducing the geometry of the individual blocks (for each block is a rigid body).

Comment: Do you have any reference images of what specifically you are wanting to achieve? What have you tried thus far that hasn't worked for you? Is it a material that you're looking for? An effect via modeling/ modifiers?

Comment: I edit the post, sorry

Comment: Are you intending on doing it during an animation, or is it for a still image?

Comment: Still image @ChristopherTiller